# GeoExplorer provokes "401 Unauthorized" request and lacks login

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

Currently I have a login problem with my deployed GeoExplorer. Everything works fine in debug mode on my local VM with the geoserver from my remote server connected. Firebug gives the following output when loading GeoExplorer.

```
GET http://localhost:9080/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&TILED=true&VERSION=1.1.1 200 OK 140ms XMLHttpRequest.js (Zeile 220)

GET http://localhost:9080/geoserver/pdf/info.json 200 OK 18ms XMLHttpRequest.js (Zeile 220)
```

However, once I deploy GeoExplorer and move it to my remote server the login button on the upper right doesn't appear anymore. Instead the basic authorization window "GeoServer Realm" pops up and Firebug shows the following "401 Unauthorized" message:

```
GET http://Server_IP/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&TILED=true&VERSION=1.1.1 200 OK 227ms GeoExplorer.js (Zeile 396)

GET http://Server_IP/geoserver/pdf/info.json 200 OK 75ms GeoExplorer.js (Zeile 396)

GET http://Server_IP/geoserver/rest/imports 401 Unauthorized 202ms GeoExplorer.js (Zeile 396)

"NetworkError: 401 Unauthorized - http://Server_IP/geoserver/rest/imports"
```

The same problem applies to the GeoExplorer that was originally installed with the OpenGeoSuite, so it rather seems to stem from the server configuration instead of the deployment process.

I've tried various things in GeoServer security setup and found threads with similar symptoms, but couldn't find a solution for us yet. Maybe someone has another useful hint?!

Another idea: Can I configure the deployed GeoExplorer that it requests GeoServer over localhost instead of the server IP? Could this help?

Comment: What version of the OpenGeo Suite are you using? The missing login button was an issue with an older version, and was fixed as of 3.0.1 if I remember correctly.

Comment: We installed the latest version on the server following: http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/installation/linux/ubuntu/suite.html
version.ini states:
suite_version=3.1
build_revision=fdace99
build_date=2013-07-05_16-33-15
build_profile=

Comment: My impression is that it's a session/cache/cookie related problem. When I load GeoExplorer in my VM the first time it runs well. When I login and reload GeoExplorer in Mozilla the Login button doesn't appear anymore and GeoExplorer fires the GET request to localhost:9080/geoserver/rest/imports which is "404 Not Found" from my VM and "401 Not Authorized" from the server. Why does GeoExplorer send this request?

Comment: Then again loading GeoExplorer on the server never shows me a Login button (neither after restarting and emptying cache in Mozilla). Here, however, I always get the "Geoserver Realm" Authentication window, I guess because GeoExplorer runs in the same servlet container as GeoServer. How can I prevent this in GeoServer?

Comment: Looks like you are mixing production mode and debug mode on the same machine in different VMs and different browsers. This can indeed cause cookie confusion. So what you should try is clear your browser's cache and cookies, and then go to the production url of your GeoExplorer. You should get a login button then.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing description. I'm using one local VM in debug mode and one remote server for production. Both invoke the GeoServer on the remote server.

VM: GeoExplorer Login/Logout and rights management works fine. Only when I'm logged in and reload the page the button disappears.

Remote server: When I load GeoExplorer of the remote server the "GeoServer Realm" authentication window pops up and GeoExplorer Login/Logout button never appears. Besides I can edit layers regardless of providing credentials or canceling authentication.

Comment: The requests in my VM are sent to localhost the ones in the remote server to the server's IP. Can this be a problem? Can I configure this during deployment? Right now I just run mvn install, set GEOEXPLORER_DATA directory and copy the .war to the remote servlet container.

Comment: OK the problem seems to stem from our redirect from port 80 to 8080 (Two machines with redirect don't work while one without redirect works). 
Originally we redirected via iptables. So I changed the approach, configuring a ProxyPass in apache and tomcat. Now the "Logout, unknown" button appears. However the "GeoServer Realm" still pops up, as well.
Could you provide me with a HowTo of your redirect method? Or is it a GeoServer configuration that still provokes the pop-up dialog? Thanks!

Comment: I am even getting the same error and still didn't get the proper answerplz elaboare http://localhost/ram/Openlayers%20Workshop/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/proxy… if%26INFO_FORMAT%3Dtext%252Fhtml%26SRS%3DEPSG%253A4326%26X%3D297%26Y%3D145 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/116528)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/116528)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do a redirect. Using Apache's ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse is proven to work fine. Also make sure to set proxy url to the proxied external url in the GeoServer config UI, under Settings - Global - Proxy Base URL. Here is an example for ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
```