# GeoServer and GeoExplorer issues setting up per-layer security

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, geoexplorer

I can't get per-layer security working...

I have the following set up:

1. A user USER, with no group membership and one role EXAMPLE_ROLE and a password
2. the role has no parent role and no properties
3. under data security I have:

   - *.*.r set to *
   - workspace.mylayer.w set to EXAMPLE_ROLE
4. All the services security is set to *.* *

But, when USER logs in to geoexplorer's saved map with mylayer in there, USER can edit, but saving returns the error message "{server}mylayer is read-only.

If I set the second secirity to workspace.mylayer.w * then that user can edit.

What's going on? What am I missing?

EDIT: using version 3.1 of OpenGeoSuite, GeoServer 2.2-SNAPSHOT

EDIT2: on looking into it further, I noticed that I don't get the login button on geoexplorer. I also get this error on Chrome's console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://tobler-v:8080/geoserver/rest/imports
```

and I wonder if this is something related to this: [GeoExplorer provokes "401 Unauthorized" request and lacks login](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68186/geoexplorer-provokes-401-unauthorized-request-and-lacks-login)

Comment: Your EDIT2 is something you should pay closer attention to. What is the URL you use to access GeoExplorer? It should be http://tobler-v:8080/geoexplorer/.

Comment: Hi @ahocevar, thanks for your response. I use that url, though I do have a proxy/reverse proxy set up with nginx so I can use tobler-v/geoexplorer. Doesn't matter, I can't get the login button to show up either way.